# Methods in ruby dont change variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby and new to programming in general. I have a piece of code in a standalone ruby script that reads data from a yaml file and assigns that data to a variable in a method. This is all done in a method.
outside the definition of the method, I call that method and print the value of the variable assigned. But, uh oh, the value of the variable that was assigned in the method is nil... Why? This has something to do with object oriented programming I assume. Can someone elaborate?

Below is the code. Thank you in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pg'
require 'yaml'

source_connection=nil

def load_configurations
    file_name = nil

    ARGV.each do|a|
      file_name = "#{a}"
    end
    dest_options = YAML.load_file(file_name)
    source_connection = dest_options['dest_name']
end

load_configurations()

puts source_connection

#####  returns nothing. why? #####
```

Comment: Looks like you incorporated suggestions in my answer to your previous question. Have you considered up/down-voting or at least leaving a comment to it?

Comment: Charles, that didnt work at all.

Answer (score 5):

In Ruby, as in most languages (all I know at least, Javascript may be an exception) there is a concept called visibility scopes.

There are four scopes in Ruby:

- global scope
- class scope
- method scope
- block scope

What it means in practice is that **local variable** defined for ex. in method is visible only in this method unless you explicitly pass in up (with method/block call param) or down (with return) the call stack.

In your case what happens is that outside the method you assign `source_connection` to nil, but then you refer to the same var name in different scope so it is assigned only there. Ruby way of solving this is either to define an **instance variable** (`@source_connection`) or to **explicitly pass** this variable into the method and then return it.

Pro tip: in Ruby last evaluation gets returned by default so you don't need to explicitly write `return source_connection`.

EDIT:
With class instance and instance variables things get a little more complicated so the best would be if I just point you in a direction of Metaprogramming Ruby book which perfectly lays out those topics.

EDIT2:
My rewrite suggestion (with a little style change - for method definition it's good to always add parentheres no matter of there are params or not. For call on other hand you may omit then if there's none or a single param - but this depends on personal taste ;)
I also changed indent to 2 spaces - I think it's most commonly used.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pg'
require 'yaml'

def load_configurations()
  file_name = nil

  ARGV.each do|a|
    file_name = "#{a}"
  end
  dest_options = YAML.load_file(file_name)
  dest_options['dest_name'] # Ruby will return last evaluation
end

source_connection = load_configurations

puts source_connection # now it will print what you expect
```

Comment: You have no mention to the word "local variable". This is crucial here.

Comment: Correct but it should be noted that most languages don't have Ruby's rather non-intuitive scoping rules for free variables.

Comment: @sawa I'm no Ruby super-pro so if you can help out please improve my answer!

Comment: @user2081579 in general what I wrote is correct, let me grab my Ruby Metaprogramming to improve this answer!

Answer (score 3):

The variable is created in the scope of the method and won't be set to the variable that is defined in the global scope. For more info this might be a nice read: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope

You should be able to do this:

```
def load_configurations
  file_name = nil

  ARGV.each do |a| 
    file_name = "#{a}"
  end

  dest_options = YAML.load_file(file_name)
  dest_options['dest_name']
end

source_connection = load_configurations
puts source_connection
```